# Evaluate $\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left(\log (j)-\log (j+x)+\frac x{2j}+\frac{3x}2\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions

I've been stuck with calculating the following series:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left(\log (j)-\log (j+x)+\frac x{2j}+\frac{3x}2\right),$$

for real $x\geq 0$.

My attempt:
Using the Frullani integral $\ln x=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}tdt$ and $\frac1k=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-kt}dt$, we have
\begin{align*}
S(x) =& \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left(\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-kt}}t-\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(k+x)t}}t+\frac{xe^{-kt}}2\right)dt+\frac{3x}2\right) \\=& \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kt}}t\left(-1+e^-kt+\frac{xt}2\right)+\frac{3x}2\right)
\end{align*}
but I encountered a problem to calculate it. Can you help me?

Comment: I think that in your last formula you should change $k$ to $j$. On the other hand, try passing the sum into the integral and solving the sum and then the integral

Comment: If $a_j(x)$ denotes the terms in the sum, then $a_j(x)\to3x/2$ as $j\to\infty$, which is non-zero, unless $x\not=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Weierstrass product for $\Gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass%27s_definition) implies
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\log(j)-\log(j+z)+\frac zj\right)=\gamma z+\log\Gamma(1+z).
$$
The series in the question (as *currently* written) diverges for $x\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left(\log (j)-\log (j+x)+\frac x{2j}+\frac{3x}2\right)$$ and use

$$\sum_{j=1}^{p}\log(j+x)=\log \left((x+1)_p\right)=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (p+x+1)}{\Gamma (x+1)}\right)$$ You  are now ready to use Stirling approximation as well as the asymptotic of harmonic number since
$$S_p=\frac{x H_p}{2}+\frac{3 p x}{2}+\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (p+1) \Gamma (x+1)}{\Gamma (p+x+1)}\right)$$